# Automatic Split Votes?

Tags: feature-request

As you all know, when you reach 1k rep, you can "split" the votes and see the number of upvotes and downvotes. Would it be possible to add a setting to auto-split, and clicking results in the total?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### No,

Showing upvote/downvote counts by default was declined  for performance reasons (performing twice the amount of database queries).

To quote [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood)'s [answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1007/232872):

> The total vote count (score) is denormalized, but the individual
> up/down vote counts are not.
>
> So to display it on every post would incur 2 vote table queries *
> number of visible questions / answers. Our DB is fast, but the vote
> table is pretty massive, and not doing a query is always faster than
> doing it.

---

If you really want/need this, a userscript has been shared [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53840/232872) which auto-clicks the vote counts once each second to get the totals.

Comment: I can't imagine needing this.